# how to record the order of a tableView managed by a NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have an NSFetchedResultsController to display a tableView.

And users are allowed to change the cells' order.

How can I record the order so that when users go to the view again,

the table displays by the order modified by users last time?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey guys I've done this.

In order to re-order managedObjects fetched by a fetchedResultsController, the most official way I think is to give the entity another attribute of int, such as "order", and give this attribute to the fetch request of a fetchedController, and in table view delegate method "move row from .. to " something like that, deal with this attribute with your hands, and if you use a fetchedController delegate, set a flag in that delegate methods to indicate that you will modity the entity yourself, and notify the delegate to do nothing but return.

Sample codes are Apple Sample code Recipes, and hints on the documentary of fetchedController!